# Display two vertical rules, at columns 79 and 87

Tags: python, fill-column

Python code now often is limited either to 80 columns, or to 88 columns.

`fci-mode` allows drawing a vertical rule at a single column, but not two.

I'd like to do something very similar in appearance to `fci-mode`, but draw two vertical lines instead of one.  The line positions don't need to depend on the value of `fill-column`: they should just always be columns 79 and 87.  I want to show two lines only for python mode.  How can I do that?

Comment: See library [`vline.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/vline.el) perhaps.

Comment: Have you tried [column-marker.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker)?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this, but instead I use a `whitespace-mode` face at 88 characters, and an `fci-mode` line at 80.